# What item should I put my enchanted book on?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I got extremley lucky when fishing and got a book with a lot of enchants...
it has thorns 2, Depth strider 3, Bane of athropods 4, quick charge 2, and channeling.

I do have a trident (2 actually, I got 2 in a row. I am lucky)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is an opinion based question, not allowed here. You can edit the question to make it based on fact.

Comment: How can I edit the question to be based on fact? There isn't really much fact.

Comment: Yeah, this unfortunately might not fit will on our site. You can take the existing answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Thorns isn't the best enchantment, so you shouldn't really put it on many things. It takes away 3 durability points if another enemy hits you and it gets damaged by the piece of armor.
- Bane of Arthropods is a really bad enchantment. It only works on a few mobs such as spiders, and silverfish (and a few more) by doing a bit more damage to them.
- Quick charge is a good enchantment that allows crossbows to charge faster (which can be useful, actually! quick charge can go up to level 3). Channeling is an enchantment that allows you to summon a bolt of lightning during a thunderstorm.
- Channeling can sometimes be useful (for collecting mob heads) but is also hard to use, because thunderstorms are very rare.
- Probably the best enchantment to use in this situation is Depth Strider 3, because it allows you to swim as fast as you can walk on land.

In this situation, **Depth Strider 3** is the enchantment to use.

Note: Thorns will also be added to your boots, which means that it will take more durability, so try adding mending or unbreaking.